# How save data in List<> array to a text file (C#)?

Tags: c#, text, save

I have a list type of array to store data named PointDataOutput. This list store data of spacial point with (i,j).

How can I save these data?

storing method is in another class:

```
// Storing method
public void ExportPointData(...)
{
    theSpace.TheCells[a,b,0].PointDataOutput.Add(theSpace.TheCells[a,b,0].Temperature);
}



int counter = 0;
for (int currentStep = 1; currentStep <= slnParameter.MaxSteps; currentStep++)
{
    // data calculation
    theSpace.TheCells[a,b,0].Temperature=....;
    // calling method of storing
    ExportPointData(...)
}

// saving data in file

if (currentStep == MaxSteps)
{
    File.Create("data.txt");
    FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);
    foreach (double x in theSpace.TheCells[a, b, 0].PointDataOutput)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(x);
    }
    writer.WriteLine(theSpace.TheCells[a, b, 0].PointDataOutput.ToString);
    writer.Close();
}
```

I don't know can I save data each time it was produce or I should wait to complete iteration and then data in the store List should be saved. I tried several times and each time I got error that there is a text file in the same name of mine!
It shows that each time program makes new file and don't save all data in one file. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the code:

1. The line `File.Create("data.txt");` is redundant.
2. You haven't closed `FileStream fs1`. It is good practice to close a file
   once you have finished with it. A good habit is to use the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) keyword
   whereever possible.

Taking into account the above, here is how I would implement the 'saving data
in file' section:

```
// saving data in file

if (currentStep == MaxSteps)
{
    using (FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
        FileAccess.Write))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1))
    {
        foreach (double x in theSpace.TheCells[a, b, 0].PointDataOutput)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(x);
        }
        writer.WriteLine(theSpace.TheCells[a, b, 0].PointDataOutput.ToString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
File.Create("data.txt");


new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
```

Already creates a new file.

Answer (score 0):

```
//File.Create("data.txt"); you don't need this line 
FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
```

problem is `File.Create` overwritten the existing file every time you call this method

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the FileStream entirely, you're creating a file then using the `StreamWriter` which can already do that and allow you to append to it.

```
string myFileName = "data.txt";
bool doIWantToAppendToTheFile = true;
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(myFileName, doIWantToAppendToTheFile);
```

This will then add additional text to your file each time, of course if you didn't want to append just set `doIWantToAppendToTheFile` to false (oh and change the names, I just named them that way to provide some clarity).   If you wanted new files each time the write method was called to have individual blobs of data you could append a datetime stamp to the file name eg:

```
string myFileName = "data" + DateTime.Now.ToString(yyyyMMdd-hhmmss) + ".txt";
```

So the filename would be `data20140220100430.txt`